# My phone keeps unpairing with my watch when it gets out of range

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-pairing

I'm using a Pebble Time smartwatch (on Pebble OS v3.13) and Xperia M4 Aqua (on Android 5.0).

Whenever my phone gets out of range it unpairs with my pebble. I end up needing to forget my phone from pebble and pair again with my phone. This is becoming frustrating, and I can't find anything relevant on [my watch's help page](http://help.getpebble.com/) so I think that this is a problem with my phone. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it also vanishing from the Bluetooth devices list?

Comment: @EthanZ yes, it is vanishing from paired bluetooth devices list

Comment: That would be a problem with your device then. Have you installed any system updates recently and can you replicate this problem with other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: @EthanZ I can still see my controller and PC on the list and they don't get removed when they are off range. I last installed system updates a few months ago- they are kinda rare.

Comment: That would make it point to Pebble then. Even if they cannot figure out what is wrong I'm sure they can help you out further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the extra information you provided in the comments, it would seem as if the Pebble app is malfunctioning, and if it isn't, pebble support will be able to direct you to who can fix this for you. While they can be a bit slow to respond, they are very good.

To contact pebble support, open the pebble app and tap the drop down menu on the top right corner (3 dots). Tap the "support" option. Choose "contact support" from the list of options that open after tapping support.